# Location of .so and .h files in Ubuntu

Tags: path, header, shared-libraries

I am trying to compile a C++ code in a Ubuntu 12.04 OS using a make file. My code requires `libxml2` and `sqlite3`. I have installed the packages using the Synaptics Package manager. However, now I do not know the path of the header(.h) files and shared object library (.so) files.

Is there a default location for these?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are default locations -- `/usr/include` for headers, `/usr/lib` for libraries -- meaning that you do *not* have to specify them in the `Makefile`.

But *do* make sure you have the corresponding `-dev` packages `libsqlite3-dev` and `libxml2-dev` installed!